# error in the number stored in the array java

Tags: java, arrays

While I was writing the code, I had to print out total 25 numbers, so I put the number 25 inside the numberArray, however when I run the program, it dd not print out 25 numbers. Instead the number of the random numbers kept changing and did not stick to the specific value. What should I do in this case to make my code print out 25 numbers?

```
public static void printArray(int[] ear) {
    
    System.out.println("ODD NUMBERS : ");
    for (int e = 0; e<ear.length ; e ++) {
        ear[e] = (int)(Math.random()* 100);
            if(ear[e]%2!=0)
            System.out.print(ear[e] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "EVEN NUMBERS : ");
    for (int e = 0; e<ear.length ; e ++) {
        ear[e] = (int)(Math.random()* 100);
            if(ear[e]%2==0)
            System.out.print(ear[e] + "  ");
    }
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numberArray = new int[25];
    printArray(numberArray);

}

}
```

Comment: Well thats because of `if(ear[e]%2!=0)`. You are printing only if this condition is true.

Comment: Then should I eliminate that statement?

Comment: You can initialise numberArray as per your requirement

Comment: How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the code, you are only printing the ODD and EVEN numbers of the array. That's why you get different outcomes on each run.

If you change the code to print the array index instead of the value you can see that you are printing

```
ODD NUMBERS : 
4  10  12  13  14  15  18  19  22  23  24  
EVEN NUMBERS : 
0  1  3  4  5  6  9  13  16  17  18  19  20  22  23
```